# No suitable driver for sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, unix, jar, driver, tomcat8

I am working on an application that accesses to a miscrosoft database (mssql).
The application is running perfectly in local. But when I deploy it on the tomcat server in Unix I have this error:

> Unable to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://...
>
> ....
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

It is really strange cause I verified that the jar (sqljdbc42.jar) is located in the correct place. 
Also the url "jdbcUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://..." is correct since it works fine in local. 
Do you have any solution? 
Thank you.

Comment: If its connecting to localhost, then everything here should be fine. Have you added jar on claaspath? if yes then check you are correctly specifying the host and port no.

Comment: What is the "correct place" for you?

Comment: @AbhishekTiwari the host ad port are correct. But what do you mean about CLASSPATH ? Cause I am using maven for dependencies.

Comment: @Jens the correct place for me is in webappas/application_name/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: @Sabrina have you tried to put it into the lib Directory of the tomcat?

Comment: @Jens yes but in vain.

Comment: try to use `jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://`

Comment: I tried it also :(

Comment: Now I verified that when I type java -version I don't get the java version. I get command not found. Can it be the problem ?

Comment: try to use this version of  jar sqljdbc4-2.0.jar

Comment: Sometimes if firewall is blocking connection on the port. It may have problems to connect. I have not idea of unix. but in windows we create inbound rule to allow connection.

Comment: I tried also to use sqljdbc4-2.0.jar.
I want to try under webapps this command: java -cp -class WEB-INF/classes/* -jar WEB-INF/lib/* but I have this error  Could not find or load main class WEB-INF.classes.*
do you have an idea ?